# Total rows and divide by columns of all tables in a list object?

Tags: r, list, datatable

I have a list object that contains several tables that contains a year column and then frequencies of particular words. Each table might be slightly different dimensions depending on range of years and words used.

| Year | word1 | word2 | word3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | 1 | 5 | 4 |
| 2010 | 2 | 3 | 5 |

I would like to create a table that sums every row (not including the year) and then divides the column value by the row sum so that it produces a table like this:

| Year | word1 | word2 | word3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | 0.1 | 0.5 | 0.4 |
| 2010 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.5 |

Is there a way to do this to a list object? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
cbind(df[1], t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) x/sum(x))))
  Year word1 word2 word3
1 2009   0.1   0.5   0.4
2 2010   0.2   0.3   0.5
```

If you have a list of such dataframes :

```
mylist <- list(df, df)
mylist
[[1]]
  Year word1 word2 word3
1 2009     1     5     4
2 2010     2     3     5

[[2]]
  Year word1 word2 word3
1 2009     1     5     4
2 2010     2     3     5

lapply(mylist, function(y) cbind(y[1], t(apply(y[-1], 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))))
[[1]]
  Year word1 word2 word3
1 2009   0.1   0.5   0.4
2 2010   0.2   0.3   0.5

[[2]]
  Year word1 word2 word3
1 2009   0.1   0.5   0.4
2 2010   0.2   0.3   0.5
```

Data used:

```
df
  Year word1 word2 word3
1 2009     1     5     4
2 2010     2     3     5
```

Comment: the lapply script worked! Thank you! Using the same data format, is there a way to set the number of decimal places? Currently, it's giving values like 0.1134922?

Comment: and to replace 0 values in the new table with a period or a hyphen? Got a lot more 0's than expected due to some row/columns having 0 frequencies.

Comment: Just insert a call to `round(x/sum(x))`.

Comment: @Jonas Thanks! I'm still really bad at R. Could you show how to "insert a call" for this?

Comment: Instead of `cbind(df[1], t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) x/sum(x))))` use `cbind(df[1], t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) round(x/sum(x),2)))` if you want to round to 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

For a single data.frame, you can use the following function:

```
doit <- function(df) {
  cbind(df[1],sweep(df[-1],1,rowSums(df[-1]),"/"))
}
```

e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(Year = 1:3, Word1 = c(1,2,3), Word2 = c(3,2,1), Word3 = c(6,6,6))
doit(df)
#  Year Word1 Word2 Word3
#1    1   0.1   0.3   0.6
#2    2   0.2   0.2   0.6
#3    3   0.3   0.1   0.6
```

If you have multiple data.frames in a list, just wrap everything with `lapply`, like `lapply(dfList,doit)`.